# How to convert from UTC to local time in moment.js?

Tags: momentjs

I have a simple use case but I cannot figure out how to convert from GMT/UTC to local time in moment.js.

Example:

```
var gmtDateTime = moment.utc("2015-10-24 20:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH").format('YYYY-MMM-DD h:mm A');
```

`console.log(gmtDateTime)` emits `2015-Oct-24 8:00 PM`, which is correct. Now I simply want to convert this to my local time, which happens to be Mountain Daylight Time. So the correct converted date would be `2015-Oct-24 2:00 PM`, because I am 6 hours earlier than GMT/UTC.

How can this be done simply with moment.js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert from GMT/UTC to local time and back using momentjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070296/how-to-convert-from-gmt-utc-to-local-time-and-back-using-momentjs)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try [`moment().local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/).

Example:

```
var gmtDateTime = moment.utc("2015-10-24 20:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH")
var local = gmtDateTime.local().format('YYYY-MMM-DD h:mm A');
```

Comment: Don't forget `:mm` in the original input.  OP was missing it too.

Comment: I would suggest to change try: moment().local() to moment.local().

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to do moment.utc($time).local().fromNow() and it converted perfect!

Answer (score 8):

However, @antti-kuosmanen answer is accepted and correct.

`moment().local()` is a correct way. But this can do in a single line. Here is how

```
var local = moment.utc("2015-10-24 20:00").local().format('YYYY-MMM-DD h:mm A');
```

No need to formating twice for the results

Cheers!! Read Simple Write Simple

Comment: this is short and clean answer