# Why conversion from utc and back using momentjs is missing a day

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc

I want to convert 2018-05-16 01:30 to utc and back

```
moment("2018-05-16 01:30").tz("America/Anchorage").utc() == "2018-05-15 17:30"
moment("2018-05-15 17:30").tz("America/Anchorage") == "2018-05-15 01:30:00"
```

It's missing a day! 2018-05-15 01:30 instead of 2018-05-16 01:30

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? var gmtDateTime = moment.utc("2015-10-24 20:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH")
var local = gmtDateTime.local().format('YYYY-MMM-DD h:mm A');

There is a topic as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321495/how-to-convert-from-utc-to-local-time-in-moment-js

Comment: @laroslav: I also saw that topic but local() wasn't what I was looking for. moment("2018-05-16 01:30") gets already processed as local. What worked for me was what I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using momentjs incorrectly. It should be used as so:

```
moment.tz("2018-05-16 01:30", "America/Anchorage").utc().format() == "2018-05-16 09:30"
moment.utc("2018-05-16 09:30", "YYYY-MM-DD H:mm").tz("America/Anchorage") == "2018-05-16 01:30"
```