# convert IST time zone to GMT using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert IST time zone to GMT format using momentjs. The date value which is coming from database is in the following way,

```
2018-07-17T10:52:39.785
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/ - or, if IST can be convert to a simple offset (like "-0800" or whatever it is) and add that to the ISO8601/parse and then convert to UTC.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321495/how-to-convert-from-utc-to-local-time-in-moment-js

Comment: @UllasHunka, that’s the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
moment("2018-07-17T10:52:39.785").utc().format()
```

See [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) docs.