# Moment timezone, convert to new timezone date time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of dates that are in utc, but i want to convert them to local time.

```
        $(function(){
            var timezone = moment.tz.guess(true);
            $('.utcDueDate').each(function(){
                var taskDateTime = $(this).text();
                var newTime = moment(taskDateTime).tz(timezone).format();
                $(this).text(newTime);
            });
        });
```

Example:
date time before: 2020-07-09 21:57:00
date time after conversion: 2020-07-09T21:57:00+02:00

I want the +2 hours to be already added in the date time, so date time after conversion is: 2020-07-09T23:57:00

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert from UTC to local time in moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321495/how-to-convert-from-utc-to-local-time-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
moment(date).add(2, 'hours');
```

Here is edit of your code:

```
        $(function(){
            var timezone = moment.tz.guess(true);
            $('.utcDueDate').each(function(){
                var taskDateTime = $(this).text();
                var newTime = moment(taskDateTime).add(2, 'hours').tz(timezone).format();
                $(this).text(newTime);
            });
        });
```

Comment: What im looking for is the final format, so the time difference is already added/deducted from the time, so its not time + x, but rather just time, i have a example at bottom of my question

Comment: Edited answer. Is it what you want?